# scala - how to get byteArray of Long value in fixed size of 8 bytes

Tags: scala

I want to get the byte array values of "Long" in fixed 8 byte array

```
scala> Long.MaxValue
res191: Long = 9223372036854775807

scala> val i:Long = Long.MaxValue
i: Long = 9223372036854775807

scala> BigInt(i).toByteArray
res192: Array[Byte] = Array(127, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)

scala> val i:Long = 100
i: Long = 100

scala> BigInt(i).toByteArray
res193: Array[Byte] = Array(100)  // what I want is Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100)

scala>
```

What I'm doing is

```
scala> var a:Array[Byte] =  Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
a: Array[Byte] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

scala> a.slice(0,8-BigInt(i).toByteArray.length) ++ BigInt(i).toByteArray
res200: Array[Byte] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100)

scala>
```

I'm not sure it is robust.. Is there a better way to get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of options:

```
val a = Array.fill[Byte](8)(0)

(a ++ BigInt(i).toByteArray).takeRight(8)
```

or

```
BigInt(i).toByteArray.reverse.padTo(8, 0).reverse
```

The second has the advantage of being robust if the value has more than 8 digits.

Comment: I'll go with the first one..as I will not encounter overflow and readable too!!